# Trouble passing an array embedded object to an ember.js route for dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic, ember.js

I am trying to make dynamic forms based upon JSON objects using Ember.js. All though the fiddle that I provide has a main navigation with other routes, they are not the problem at hand so I will skip them in the explanation.

On the forms page, I have a sub-navigation that creates links for each form:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="forms">
    <h3>Forms</h3>
    <ul class="mainNav2">
    {{#each}}
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'form' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <div class="formContent">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
```

This route passes the JSON object containing the multiple forms data to the forms template:

```
App.FormsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return forms;
    }
});
```

This part seems to work fine.
Once you click the links, it should then load a sub-resource.

```
this.resource('forms', function(){
    this.resource('form', { path: ':form_id' });
});
```

This is the object array I am passing:

```
var forms = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Submissions",
        "elements": [
            {
                "inputType": "text",
                "inputName": "Customer_Name"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "text",
                "inputName": "Customer_Number"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "checkbox",
                "inputName": "Outbound_Call"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "submit",
                "inputName": "submit"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Initial Interview",
        "elements": [
            {
                "inputType": "text",
                "inputName": "Business_Name"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "text",
                "inputName": "Business_Hours"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "checkbox",
                "inputName": "Business_Something"
            },
            {
                "inputType": "submit",
                "inputName": "submit"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I am able to access the 'id' and the 'name' in the object, but I am unable to access the 'elements' array in the 'form' template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="form">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    {{#each}}
    <label for="{{elements.inputName}}">{{elements.inputName}}</label><input type="{{elements.inputType}}" name="{{elements.inputName}}" />
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

If I change the 'form' template to not run the `{{#each}}`, it will load the `{{name}}` properly. I am still unaware how to load the 'inputName' and 'inputType' into the 'form' template. That is where it appears to break.

[Partial Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/t63vR/2/)

[Broken JSfiddle with the form inputs included](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/t63vR/)

I've never actually asked a question on SO before, but if anyone could point me in the right direction of how to pass the nested elements array into the 'form' template I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your model doesn't have a matching property (to the dynamic slug in the route), IE `form_id` you need to tell ember how to generate the link. The `serialize` hook saves the day.

```
App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return forms[0].elements;
    },
    serialize:function(model){
        return {form_id:Em.get(model, 'id')};   
    }
});
```

The each helper must iterate over an array.  When you don't specify anything to iterate over

```
{{#each}}

{{/each}}
```

you are essentially saying this

```
{{#each this in this}}
    the context of this in here is the item
{{/each}}
```

You can be more specific and tell it what to iterate over and what to name the context.

```
{{#each item in this}}
    the context of item in here is the item
{{/each}}


{{#each item in elements}}
    the context of item in here is the item, and we're iterating the
    elements array, which might live on the controller or model
{{/each}}


{{#each item in elements}}
    <label for="{{item.inputName}}">{{item.inputName}}</label><input type="{{item.inputType}}" name="{{item.inputName}}" />
{{/each}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t63vR/5/